# Why can't I win a domination victory in Civilization 5?

Tags: civilization-5

I have explored the entire map with my caravel, but when I go to victory progress it still says that the Iroquois have their capital, even though they clearly don't. I should let you all know that I am on the play as you go tutorial, but I still think it should be winnable.
https://gyazo.com/fe4d19200dd11d7df6763f3019150b04

Comment: Scenarios like a tutorial don't really have to follow those rules.  If it wasn't written to win that way, you won't.  Try a full game.

Comment: Also, it probably doesn't apply for the Tutorial, but there's an Advanced Setting when starting a new game, that requires all the units of a nation killed for them to be declared conquered, instead of just capturing all their cities.

Comment: Look at the bottom right of your map, it looks like there is white border just at the south pole. That might be it :)

Answer (score 1):

**Onondaga**

The Iroquois capital city will be named Onondaga. If it is on the map and you have it captured then this is a **bug**.

If you have not captured Onondaga yet, then you must find it. I would say for certain that it is a bug but your screenshot above doesn't include a picture of Onondaga, so I'm going of the information that is available to me.

Answer (score -1):

Just because you have explored the entire map does not mean there are not more cities that were founded after you explored a particular area. I have that happen in every game -- a place where I explored appears empty to me because I do not have any units nearby, but when I go through there again, there is a now a thriving city in my way.

If you want to keep active, accurate accounts of your map status, send scouts to every corner of the map, so that you have no "fog of war" and you'll more than likely find a city in a little nook that you previously explored.

Comment: Domination victory requires that you capture all the original capitals, and those won't be created after the first turn. Original capitals also can't be destroyed. If the original poster has in fact explored the entire map then the Iroquois original capital would be visible somewhere on the map, even if it's not currently in the line of sight of one of the OP's units.

Comment: I was under the impression that a capital could be moved to a new city if it was captured, thus requiring the new capital to be captured as well, but perhaps that was an older version of Civ I'm thinking of.

Comment: @TimS., Current Capital will be indeed moved. But requirement for Victory is the Original Capital.